# How closure captures values in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am running the below code -

```
class Element {
    var name: String
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("Element is deinitializing...")
    }
}

var element: Element? = Element(name: "Silver")

var closure = {
    print(element?.name ?? "default value")
}

print(isKnownUniquelyReferenced(&element))
element?.name = "Gold"
element = nil
closure()
```

and it prints -

```
true
Element is deinitializing...
default value
```

In the above, isn't the closure captures `element` strongly? How the `element` is getting nil inside the `closure`?

Comment: A variable on top level is declared as part of the current module and the closure captures that module. It actually accesses `ProjectModule.element` This is similar to capturing `self`. You can prevent that behavior using capture list `[element = element]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [Swift Programming Guide - Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html)

> A closure can capture constants and variables from the surrounding context in which it’s defined. The closure can then refer to and modify the values of those constants and variables from within its body, even if the original scope that defined the constants and variables no longer exists.

A closure captures variables, not the contents of variables. When we are talking about local variables in a function (which are normally allocated on stack), it makes sure they are accessible even when the function exits and other local variables are deallocated, therefore we can do things like this:

```
func myFunc() {
  var array: [Int] = []

  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // executed when myFunc has already returned!
    array.append(10)
  }
}
```

Your example is similar. The closure captures the variable. This is a variable on module level, therefore its scope always exists. When you reassign its value, it will affect the value read inside the closure.

Or, in other words, the closure will be equivalent to:

```
var closure = {
    print(CurrentModule.element?.name ?? "default value")
}
```

where `CurrentModule` is the name of your main module (which is usually the name of your project).

To prevent this behavior and capture the value of the variable instead, we can use *closure capture list*. Unfortunately, the official documentation does not properly explain what exactly is a capture list. Basically, using a capture list you declare variables local to the closure using *values* that are available when the closure is created.

For example:

```
var closure = { [capturedElement = element] in
    print(capturedElement?.name ?? "default value")
}
```

This will create a new variable `capturedElement` inside the closure, with the current value of variable `element`.

Of course, usually we just write:

```
var closure = { [element] in
    print(element?.name ?? "default value")
}
```

which is a shorthand for `[element = element]`.

Comment: This is either wrong or outdated. Referrring to function-local vars from inside a closure (such as in your first code block) causes a compiler error.

Comment: @JMC it does not.

Comment: @JMC Although I use this all the time, I still tested the code now. It works without problems. Maybe you should create a question? I cannot help you in the comments.

Comment: My bad, it produces a compiler error only when strict concurrency checking is enabled. iirc, that will be the default behavior of Swift 6.

Comment: @JMC There is no reason why this shouldn't work but you are probably thinking about some specific `Task` use case.

Comment: In this example there is nothing wrong with it. But in the future, in Swift 6, the compiler will no longer allow capturing local vars in potentially-concurrent closures like in your first code block. Strict concurrency checking mode is essentially meant to check for Swift 6 compatibility, that's why it doesn't compile if that mode is enabled in xcode.